# Multiple Controller throwing error in my Angular JS application

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am a beginner in Angular JS. I know that below declaration is required in the js file to make angular JS Controller work.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('ctrlOne', function(){
});
```

But recently got some code from internet where the declaration is not made for the app and controllers like above. But there are only controller function defined, still working fine but not in my case.

[image: View Code from Internet]

[image: Script Code from Internet]

```
function ctrlOne($scope){

};

function ctrlTwo($scope){

};
```

Please find my code below and output. Please correct me.

```
<div ng-app>
    <input type="text" ng-model="data.message" />
    <h1>{{ data.message }}</h1>

    <div ng-controller="ctrlOne">
        <input type="text" ng-model="data.message" />
        <h1>{{ data.message }}</h1>
    </div>

    <div ng-controller="ctrlTwo">
        <input type="text" ng-model="data.message" />
        <h1>{{ data.message }}</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="App.js"></script>
```

**App.js:**

```
function ctrlOne($scope){

};

function ctrlTwo($scope){

};
```

[image: Please find the screenshot with error]

Please can any one help me to figure out where I went wrong. Your advice's are welcomed.

Please find JSFIDDLE Link : [Have done above coding here](https://jsfiddle.net/nareshjavastudy/19LLp6sm/)

[image: Screen shot of My Coding from Local Drive - View Part]
[image: Screen shot of My Coding from Local Drive - App.js]

Comment: Please make a plunker/fiddle and I can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your html to include `myApp` module name like so:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
...
  <div ng-controller="ctrlOne">
      <input type="text" ng-model="data.message" />
      <h1>{{ data.message }}</h1>
  </div>
...
</div>
```

Angular needs to know what is the name of your *root* module. [`ng-app`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp) directive specifies just that:

> Use this directive to auto-bootstrap an AngularJS application. The
>   ngApp directive designates the root element of the application and is
>   typically placed near the root element of the page - e.g. on the
>   `<body>` or `<html>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of initializing an angular app. One is to define `ng-app` in html or you can manually bootstrap angular app. 
You need to figure out where is the app getting initialized. Because in your html you are using `ng-app=''`. you should provide it with app name.

Comment: Even after removing as u advised. I am getting the same output error which i have in my screenshot

Comment: After removing did you check, if it is gettin bootstraped somewhere else in your code ?

Comment: No, you need to completely remove `ng-app`.

Comment: Hi ashfaq, thanks for your response. Have JSFIDDLE attached, can you please have a look at it. I have seen other example working fine for the similar kind of code. Thanks in advance.
https://jsfiddle.net/nareshjavastudy/19LLp6sm/

Comment: In your fiddle you have not attached the angular.js file. Plus you have no app defined anywhere. the code sample you are trying to copy from internet is not complete. You must have missed something.

Comment: I have editted my question with Screen shot of my code. So just for clarification, I am confirming that, 

without var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('ctrlOne', function(){
});

Angular JS application wont work properly? Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102567/discussion-between-naresh-raj-and-ashfaq-p).